# Dereferencing Box<T> gives back value instead of reference

Tags: rust

I can't seem to figure out why:

```
let a = Box::new(5i32);
let _:() = *a;
```

tells me that the assigned type on the second line is `i32` and not `&i32` since `Deref.deref()` (which I assume is being called at `*a`), returns `&T`.

Also, if I were to call `deref()` myself:

```
let _:() = <Box<i32> as Deref>::deref(&a);
```

I get the expected `&i32`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`*foo` is not the same as calling `foo.deref()`. If it were, you'd *never* be able to actually dereference a value. ^_^

`*` is syntactic sugar for "call `Deref::deref` and then go into the address provided". This is just what people expect from that operator. `Deref` exists to make it extensible.

That last bit glosses over some details that [bluss' answer covers much better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33654412/155423).

See also:

- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)

Comment: The second part of this answer is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 21):

Dereferencing doesn't necessarily produce an (intermediate) value. Consider

```
let b = Box::new(1);
(*b).clone();
```

The method `i32::clone()` is called with a `&self` argument where the reference points to the value inside the box, not to a temporary value that could be produced by `(*b)`.

The trait [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) is part of implementing dereferencing (just like [`DerefMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html)).

There is no corresponding trait to what `*` can additionally do on a box: Move the inner value out and discard the box; this is colloquially called `DerefMove` but remains a compiler-hardcoded box speciality at this point.

When the compiler sees `(*a)`, it has to infer whether to use `Deref`, `DerefMut` or “`DerefMove`”; it is inferred from how the expression is used: if you call a `&self` method on the result, `Deref` is used, for example.

Edited: Inherently copyable types (trait [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)), use `Deref` followed by copy instead of “`DerefMove`”; this is then no longer resticted to Box, but works with all smart pointers.

Comment: Moving out isn't limited to `Box`; it also [applies to references](http://is.gd/Wgqq2v). Of course, you can't actually move out of a reference, but it tries.

Comment: @bluss This helps a lot - but given my updated knowledge of derefing and a little testing, `*` doesn't discard the box after extracting the value out, as I expected. Since `Deref.deref()` as implemented on `Box` does a share borrow (ie `&self`), it leaves the original owner of the `Box` intact. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Shepmaster Well it has an error that says it's not possible, you mean :-)

Comment: @Mansour Yes, that's right, I forgot the case that Shepmaster explains and applies to your case -- Deref followed by Copy. An integer implements the `Copy` trait.

Comment: But as explained, the `(*a).clone()` case does not copy the integer even if it's a `Box<i32>`, you call with a reference pointing into the box.

Answer (score 1):

`Box` has an `as_ref()` implementation which simply returns a reference to the inner value:

```
let a = Box::new(5i32);
let _: &i32 = &a;
```