# How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?

Tags: rust, unsafe

What is the implementation for this function:

```
fn unbox<T>(value: Box<T>) -> T {
    // ???
}
```

The only function in the documentation that looks like what I want is `Box::into_raw`. The following will type check:

```
fn unbox<T>(value: Box<T>) -> T {
    *value.into_raw()
}
```

This gives the error `error[E0133]: dereference of raw pointer requires unsafe function or block`. Wrapping it in an `unsafe { ... }` block fixes it.

```
fn unbox<T>(value: Box<T>) -> T {
    unsafe { *value.into_raw() }
}
```

Is this the correct implementation? If so, why is it unsafe? What does it mean?

Perhaps this question shows my general uncertainty of how `Box`s actually work.

Comment: Note: in your proposed implementation, you are leaking the memory allocated by `Box`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Currently the Rust compiler doesn't allow moving out of a raw pointer.

Comment: @TSK: It does, actually. See the `core::ptr::read` method.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I mean OP's example does not leak memory as it won't even compile (there is no `ptr::read` here).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Dereference the value:

```rust
fn unbox<T>(value: Box<T>) -> T {
    *value
}
```

There's a nightly associated function [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_inner) you can use as well:

```rust
#![feature(box_into_inner)]
fn unbox<T>(value: Box<T>) -> T {
    Box::into_inner(value)
}
```

---

Way back in pre-1.0 Rust, heap-allocated values were *very special* types, and they used the sigil `~` (as in `~T`). Along the road to Rust 1.0, most of this special-casing was removed... but not all of it.

This particular specialty goes by the name "deref move", and there's a [proto-RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/997) about supporting it as a first-class concept. Until then, the answer is "because `Box` is special".

See also:

- [Dereferencing Box<T> gives back value instead of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33653946/155423)

Comment: Why did I not try that? The `Deref` trait appears to return an `&T`. Do I not understand what the `*` operator does, or are boxes really just special?

Comment: @Calebmer there's [a difference between `*` and `Deref`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31624743/155423), **and** boxes are special in this case.

Comment: I wish there was an explicit method instead :(

Comment: Would much code break if an explicit method was added and the special behavior was removed? Can this be changed in an edition?

Comment: @JosephGarvin It couldn't be a *method* on `Box`, but you could add an associated function (`impl Box { fn whatever(this: Self) -> T }`). This could be added immediately if you felt like submitting a PR. *Removing* the special behavior would likely break far too many things and seems unlikely to be accepted, but potentially possible.

Comment: But when T is a reference to an object trait &dyn T   how can we get the inner concret type ?

Comment: @tipografieromonah if you have a reference, you can't get an owned value. See [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423); [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423). If you want a reference, see [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423); [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423).

Comment: Thiis one clarified my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object

Comment: It looks like there's an explicit method coming. `Box::into_inner()` currently in nightly.