# How to call a method that consumes self on a boxed trait object?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

I have the following sketch of an implementation:

```
trait Listener {
    fn some_action(&mut self);
    fn commit(self);
}

struct FooListener {}

impl Listener for FooListener {
    fn some_action(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", "Action!!");
    }
    
    fn commit(self) {
        println!("{:?}", "Commit");
    }
}

struct Transaction {
    listeners: Vec<Box<dyn Listener>>,
}

impl Transaction {
    fn commit(self) {
        // How would I consume the listeners and call commit() on each of them?
    }
}

fn listener() {
    let transaction = Transaction {
        listeners: vec![Box::new(FooListener {})],
    };
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I can have `Transaction`s with listeners on them that will call the listener when something happens on that transaction. Since `Listener` is a trait, I store a `Vec<Box<Listener>>`.

I'm having a hard time implementing `commit` for `Transaction`. Somehow I have to consume the boxes by calling `commit` on each of the stored `Listener`s, but I can't move stuff out of a box as far as I know.

How would I consume my listeners on commit?

Comment: Moving "stuff" out of a box is easy; [you just dereference it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264041/how-do-i-get-an-owned-value-out-of-a-box). Your case is more complicated because you no longer know how big the value stored inside the box was. This means you get an error: *cannot move a value of type Listener: the size of Listener cannot be statically determined*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Applying `commit` to the boxed object is not allowed because the trait object doesn't know its size (and it's not constant at compile-time). Since you plan to use listeners as boxed objects, what you can do is acknowledge that `commit` will be invoked on the box and change its signature accordingly:

```
trait Listener {
    fn some_action(&mut self);
    fn commit(self: Box<Self>);
}

struct FooListener {}

impl Listener for FooListener {
    fn some_action(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", "Action!!");
    }

    fn commit(self: Box<Self>) {
        println!("{:?}", "Commit");
    }
}
```

This enables `Transaction` to compile as you wrote it, because inside the implementation of `FooListener` the size of `Self` is well known and it is perfectly possible to move the object out of the box and consume both.

The price of this solution is that `Listener::commit` now *requires* a `Box`. If that is not acceptable, you could declare both `commit(self)` and `commit_boxed(self: Box<Self>)` in the trait, requiring all types to implement both, possibly using private functions or macros to avoid code duplication. This is not very elegant, but it would satisfy both the boxed and unboxed use case without loss of performance.

Comment: Does this work for trait objects? Like, if I have a `let box: Box<Listener>`, can I call `box.commit();`?

Comment: I ask because `Self` is going to be FooListener, not Listener, correct?

Comment: @Lucretiel Yes, the answer (and likely the question) was written with trait objects in mind.

Comment: Which types can be assigned to the first parameter `self` of struct methods? Is there any further statement about such usage? (I can't find it in the official tutorial.)

Comment: @BobGreen See e.g. [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/associated-items.html?highlight=self#methods). In summary, you can use `Self` optionally wrapped in a smart pointer like `Box` or `Arc`. See also my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902388/1600898) which shows how to achieve the same without `Box<Self>`.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer shows what to do when you have the agency to modify the original `Listener` trait. If you don't have that option, i.e. if you control the `Transaction` type, but not `Listener` and its implementations, read on.

First we create a helper trait that is object-safe because none of its methods consume `self`:

```
trait DynListener {
    fn some_action(&mut self);
    fn commit(&mut self);
}
```

To use this trait everywhere `Listener` is usable, we will provide a *blanket* implementation of the trait. Normally such an implementation would implement `DynListener` for all types `T: Listener`. But that doesn't work here because `Listener::commit()` requires consuming `self`, and `DynListener::commit()` only receives a reference, so calling `Listener::commit()` would fail to compile with "cannot move out of borrowed content". To work around that, we implement `DynListener` for `Option<T>` instead. This allows us to use `Option::take()` to get an owned value to pass to `Listener::commit()`:

```
impl<T: Listener> DynListener for Option<T> {
    fn some_action(&mut self) {
        // self is &mut Option<T>, self.as_mut().unwrap() is &mut T
        self.as_mut().unwrap().some_action();
    }

    fn commit(&mut self) {
        // self is &mut Option<T>, self.take().unwrap() is T
        self.take().unwrap().commit();
    }
}
```

`DynListener::commit()` takes value out of the `Option`, calls `Listener::commit()` on the value, and leaves the option as `None`. This compiles because the value is not "unsized" in the blanket implementation where the size of each individual `T` is known. The downside is that we are allowed to call `DynListener::commit()` multiple times on the same option, with all attempts but the first panicking at run time.

The remaining work is to modify `Transaction` to make use of this:

```
struct Transaction {
    listeners: Vec<Box<dyn DynListener>>,
}

impl Transaction {
    fn commit(self) {
        for mut listener in self.listeners {
            listener.commit();
        }
    }
}

fn listener() {
    let transaction = Transaction {
        listeners: vec![Box::new(Some(FooListener {}))],
    };
    transaction.commit();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc75b2cf3407fc28cbb8db77b5f55740)

Answer (score 4):

With the [`unsized_locals`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html) feature enabled, the natural code [works as-is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7552ddb6182b779e8c81a9011c2fab78):

```
// 1.37.0-nightly 2019-06-03 6ffb8f53ee1cb0903f9d
#![feature(unsized_locals)]

// ...

impl Transaction {
    fn commit(self) {
        for l in self.listeners {
            l.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to user4815162342's answer, I wrote a macro to generate `commit_boxed(self: Box<Self>)` [here](https://crates.io/crates/box-self).

Furthermore, after adding `self: Box<Self>` signature,  you can easily implement trait Listener for `Box<dyn Listener>`. That means you can call `box.commit()` just as `listener.commit()`.

```
impl Listener for Box<dyn Listener> {
    fn some_action(&mut self) {
        //...
    }
    fn commit(self) {
        Listener::commit_boxed(self)
    }
    fn commit_boxed(self:Box<Self>) {
        Listener::commit_boxed(*self)
    }
}
```