# How to Box a trait that has associated types?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I'm very new to Rust so I may have terminology confused.

I want to use the [hashes](https://github.com/RustCrypto/hashes) crates to do some hashing and I want to dynamically pick which algorithm (sha256, sha512, etc.) to use at runtime.

I'd like to write something like this:

```
let hasher = match "one of the algorithms" {
    "sha256" => Box::new(Sha256::new()) as Box<Digest>,
    "sha512" => Box::new(Sha512::new()) as Box<Digest>
    // etc...
};
```

I sort of get that that doesn't work because the associated types required by `Digest` aren't specified. If I attempt to fill them in:

```
"sha256" => Box::new(Sha256::new()) as Box<Digest<<OutputSize = U32, BlockSize = U64>>>,
```

I'm left with an error: `the trait 'digest::Digest' cannot be made into an object`. I think this approach will fail anyway because `match` will be returning slightly different types in cases where different algorithms have different associated types.

Am I missing something obvious? How can I dynamically create an instance of something that implements a trait and then hold on to that thing and use it through the trait interface?

Comment: You could make a wrapper type and a trait of your own that implements the interface you actually need without associated types. Boxing such a trait will work.

Comment: Related: [How can I have a vector of objects that differ by their associated type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28932450/155423)

Comment: @user4815162342 I think that's worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 8):

The message refers to [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html#object-safety) ([longer article](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/)). The [`Digest` trait](https://docs.rs/digest/0.7.2/digest/trait.Digest.html) has two incompatibilities:

1. It [uses associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#trait-objects-with-associated-types) (this can be worked around by explicitly setting all type parameters to values compatible for all `Digest` objects).
2. It has a method (`fn result(self) -> …`) taking `self` by value. You won't be able to call it, which ruins usability of this trait.

Once a trait object is created, information about its subtype-specific features such as memory layout or associated types is erased. All calls to the trait object's methods are done via a vtable pointer. This means they all must be compatible, and Rust can't allow you to call any methods that could vary in these aspects.

A workaround is to create your custom wrapper trait/adapter that is object-compatible. I'm not sure if that's the best implementation, but it does work:

```
trait Digest {
    type Assoc;
    fn result(self);
}

struct Sha;

impl Digest for Sha {
    type Assoc = u8;
    fn result(self) {}
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

trait MyWrapper {
    fn result(&mut self); // can't be self/Sized
}

impl<T: Digest> MyWrapper for Option<T> {
    fn result(&mut self) {
        // Option::take() gives owned from non-owned
        self.take().unwrap().result() 
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut digest: Box<MyWrapper> = Box::new(Some(Sha));
    digest.result();
}
```

Comment: I wonder if one could implement `result` as accepting `self: Box<Self>` as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625787/1600898). That way the `Option` would no longer be necessary, and compile-time prevention of calling `result` twice would be restored.