# Box inverse traits/Where clauses in boxes

Tags: generics, rust

I've run into the problem of not being able to use where clauses in `Box`es and other generic structs. This is useful for generic communicative adding. (A+B=B+A). An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(Box<U where T: Add<U, Output = T>>),
    Baz(Box<U where T: Sub<U, Output = T>>),
}
```

This can be semi-done using `where` clauses in the type definition:

```
enum FooHack<T, A, S>
where
    A: Add<T, Output = T>,
    S: Sub<T, Output = T>,
{
    Bar(A),
    Baz(S),
    Dummy(PhantomData<T>), // to stop the compiler from complaining
}
```

The type signature for `FooHack` requires `A` and `S` be concrete types. Is there a strategy so that `A` and `S` can be generic?

Comment: `A` and `S` are already generic. You seem to want to use trait objects instead.

Comment: *The type signature for FooHack requires `A` and `S` be concrete types* — yes, that's kind of the *point* of a type being generic; you fill it in with concrete types when you go to use it.

Comment: @E_net4 I do want to use trait objects, but I can't find a way to express it in the terms provided

Comment: @Shepmaster You are correct, but what if I want to change Baz to something that also applies to `T: Sub<S, Output=T>` ? This would require a new type, I'm looking for a way to do it with trait objects.

Comment: See also [How to Box a trait that has associated types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48027839/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're already aware of [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html)? That's the exact match for your purpose to have `U` dynamically change for the fixed `T`.

However, two problems prevent the direct usage of `Add` or `Sub` as a trait object:

1. `Add` and `Sub` aren't object-safe, as it expects a by-value `self` argument.
2. Trait objects are existential over `Self`, but you want trait objects that are existential over `RHS` of `Add`/`Sub`.

Therefore you'll have to do extra work to introduce intermediate traits:

```
use std::ops::Add;

trait MyAdd<T> {
    fn my_add(&self, other: T) -> T;
}

impl<T, U> MyAdd<T> for U
where
    T: Add<U, Output = T>,
    U: Clone,
{
    fn my_add(&self, other: T) -> T {
        other + self.clone()
    }
}

enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(Box<MyAdd<T>>),
}
```

If you don't want `U: Clone`, there are options depending on your usage:

- Assume `T: Add<&'a U, Output = T>` instead of `T: Add<U, Output = T>`
- Use `self: Box<Self>` instead of `&self` in `fn my_add`

## Edit: operator overloading

The proxy trait `MyAdd<T>` above doesn't proxy operator overloading by itself; thus you'll have to manually implement `std::ops::Add` for this.

```
// Coherence error
impl<T> Add<Box<MyAdd<T>>> for T {
    type Output = T;
    fn add(self, other: Box<MyAdd<T>>) -> Self::Output {
        other.my_add(self)
    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't work due to coherence restrictions. This restriction is fundamental because it's always possible that a sibling crate has an impl like `impl<T> Add<T> for TypeDefinedInTheSiblingCrate`, which surely overlaps with the impl above.

One possible workaround is to use [the newtype pattern](https://rustbyexample.com/generics/new_types.html):

```
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

impl<T> Add<Box<MyAdd<T>>> for Wrapper<T> {
    type Output = Wrapper<T>;
    fn add(self, other: Box<MyAdd<T>>) -> Self::Output {
        Wrapper(other.my_add(self.0))
    }
}
```

Then you can write things like `Wrapper(x) + boxed_myadd_value + another_myadd_value`.

Comment: How would this work for operator overloading? How would I get `MyAdd` called if the inside of `Bar(x)` was applied like `x + v` where `v` is of type `T`?

Comment: @Flarp edited my answer assuming you want `v - x` direction (instead of `x - v`) where `x` is from `Baz(x)`. If you really want `x - v` direction, then it works without hitting coherence restriction. But in this case, the arguments are flipped from the original `T: Sub<U, Output = T>` trait bound (which means `(v : T) - (x : U)`).

Comment: Thanks! Sucks it can't be done without new types, though.