# Cannot move out of borrowed content, with no borrowed content

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm working on building a REST API using Rust and Rocket. I have an endpoint at which I create a new user, defined as follows:

```
/// View with which to create a user
#[post("/users", format = "application/json", data = "<user_data>")]
fn create_user(user_data: Json<UserData>, db: DB) -> Status<Json<Value>> {
    let conn = db.conn();
    let _new_user_result = user_data.into_new_user(&conn);
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Note that there is no borrowed content here; both `user_data` and `db` are owned. Still, I get the following error on compilation:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/views/user_account.rs:75:28
   |
75 |     let _new_user_result = user_data.into_new_user(&conn);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

For reference, the function signature of `into_new_user` is

```
fn into_new_user(self, conn: &SqliteConnection) -> Result<NewUser, Status<Json<Value>>> {
    ...
}
```

What is going on here? This error would be much easier to understand if I were actually borrowing anything, but given that I own everything in question, I'm baffled.

```
$ rustc --version; cargo --version
rustc 1.22.0-nightly (a47c9f870 2017-10-11)
cargo 0.23.0-nightly (e447ac7e9 2017-09-27)
```

Comment: Example on the rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=21175b41b1adcbf3a28c1f6affc74ccd&version=stable

Comment: Putting that example together suggests the answer: `user_data` is _not_ an owned `UserData` object. It's a `Json<UserData>` object, where `Json<T>` dereferences to `T`. It happens that `Json<T>` is only used for its constructor, but the compiler doesn't know that. Now I just need to figure out how to solve this, and I'll write it up as a solution.

Answer (score 7):

The issue here was with the type of `user_data`. Specifically, and exactly as written in the function signature, its type is `Json<UserData>`.

`Json<T>` is a wrapper type which tells Rocket how to wrap and unwrap JSON values; it's a convenience method which wraps your struct, but doesn't store any extra data. It therefore implements `Deref<Target = T>`, which lets you mostly ignore it. However, that only works when you don't try to consume it.

Types which implement `Deref<Target=T>` can *generally* be used as if they were a `T`; the compiler handles the indirection for you. However, what's actually going on in that function call is something more like `<Json<UserData> as Deref<Target=UserData>>::deref().into_new_user();`, and that's where the problem happens: `deref` is defined as `fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target`. The borrow happens implicitly and invisibly, but it's there.

The `Json` type isn't necessary anymore in this case; it's only there to deserialize the `UserData` struct. Therefore, we can solve the problem by discarding it. The `Json::into_inner` method discards the `Json` wrapper, giving you an owned `UserData`. This can then be consumed as planned. Put together, the function should look like this:

```
fn create_user(user_data: Json<UserData>, db: DB) -> Status<Json<Value>> {
    let conn = db.conn();
    let _new_user_result = user_data.into_inner().into_new_user(&conn);
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: Well done. I could have found that because I already had the same issue with `Deref`. Maybe you should open an issue on github to ask a more explicit error message: `Borrowed here: user_data.deref()` for example

Comment: [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/3650362) is related. If `DerefMove` ever becomes a thing, the currently-erroneous code could be made correct.