# What happens in memory when ownership is transferred out of a box?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, ownership

Does the variable `s` in `print_struct` refer to data on the heap or on the stack?

```rust
struct Structure {
    x: f64,
    y: u32,
    /* Use a box, so that Structure isn't copy */
    z: Box<char>,
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct_boxed = Box::new(Structure {
        x: 2.0,
        y: 325,
        z: Box::new('b'),
    });
    let my_struct_unboxed = *my_struct_boxed;
    print_struct(my_struct_unboxed);
}

fn print_struct(s: Structure) {
    println!("{} {} {}", s.x, s.y, s.z);
}
```

As I understand it, `let my_struct_unboxed = *my_struct_boxed;` transfers the ownership away from the box, to `my_struct_unboxed`, and then to `s` in the function `print_struct`.

What happens with the actual data? Initially it is copied from the stack onto the heap by calling `Box::new(...)`, but is the data some how *moved* or copied back to the stack at some point? If so, how? And when is `drop` called? When `s` goes out of scope?

Comment: `/* Use a box, so that Structure isn't copy */` This is not necessary: structs never implicitly implement `Copy`. This used to be the case in old (pre-1.0) versions of Rust, though, so if you got that from a book/article/etc., it's very out of date.

Comment: @trentcl thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

The `Structure` data in `my_struct_boxed` exists on the heap and the `Structure` data in `my_struct_unboxed` exists on the stack.

Therefore *naïvely* speaking (no compiler optimizations), a move or copy operation when dereferencing (`*`) your `Box` will always involve copying of the data. On the borrow-checker/static-analysis side, since the `Copy` trait is not implemented for `Structure`, this represents a transfer of ownership of the data to the `my_struct_unboxed` variable.

When you call `print_struct`, another copy would take place that would copy the bits in memory representing your `Structure` from the local variable to the function's arguments call-stack. Semantically, this again represents a transfer of ownership into the `print_struct` function.

Finally when `print_struct` goes out of scope, it drops the `Structure` which it owns.

---

[Reference: `std::marker::Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)

Excerpt

> It's important to note that in these two examples, the only difference
>   is whether you are allowed to access [your variable] after the assignment. Under the
>   hood, both a copy and a move can result in bits being copied in
>   memory, although this is sometimes optimized away.

Note the last part "this is sometimes optimized away". This is why the earlier descriptions were simplified to assume no compiler optimizations i.e. naïve. In a lot of cases, the compiler will aggressively optimize and inline the code especially with higher values for the `opt-level` flag.

Comment: Do you have a reference for what you are saying here? I am suspicious that Rust would be such a fast language if all these copies that you mention were always being made...

Comment: Ok, so to be clear, there are two meanings of the word copy being used. *Copy* as in the trait that allows us to create two instances of a variable from one instance, and *copy* in the sense of copying the low-level bits between frames on the stack and to/from the heap, right?

Comment: Yes. For the compiler, everything by default has move semantics unless your type implements the `Copy` trait. For simplicity, let's refer to the bit-level memory copying as `memcpy`, the underlying function used for copying

Answer (score 2):

> If so, how?

Both "copy" and "move" are semantically `memcpy` (though that may be optimised to something else, or even nothing whatsoever).

> And when is `drop` called? When `s` goes out of scope?

Yes. When `print_struct` ends it cleans up its local scope, and drops `s`.

Comment: So at what point in the code is the memory on the heap freed?

Comment: The Box is dropped (and its memory freed) when it's deref'd. Box is special-cased in the compiler to move on deref' (there have been requests / RFCs about a hypothetical DerefMove but so far it remains unavailable to "userland" Rust).

Comment: Is it possible through compiler optimisations that `s` actually refers to the data on the heap and that it is only freed after `s` has gone out of scope?

Comment: No, that would be the case if `s` was of type `Box<Structure>`

Comment: [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)

Comment: Isn't the box dropped (i.e. the memory freed) at the end of the scope it's defined in? The borrow checker makes sure that the memory isn't used anymore after the move, but I was assuming the actual drop happens later. (I may very well be wrong.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach looking at the MIR output, seems you are right