# Why do I get "cannot move out of `item` because it is borrowed" for a custom type but not a Box?

Tags: rust

Code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::{mem, ptr, fmt};
use std::ops::Deref;

enum Unsafety {
    Normal
}
enum ImplPolarity { Positive }
struct TraitRef;
struct Ty;
struct ImplItem;

enum ItemKind {
    Impl(Unsafety,
             ImplPolarity,
             Option<TraitRef>, // (optional) trait this impl implements
         Box<Ty>, // self
    ),
}

struct Item {
    node: ItemKind,
}

pub struct P<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: Box<T>
}

impl<T: 'static> P<T> {
    pub fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        *self.ptr
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for P<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.ptr
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut items = Vec::<P<Item>>::new();

    let mut item2: Item;

    for item in items.drain(..) {

        if let ItemKind::Impl(Unsafety::Normal,
                                   ImplPolarity::Positive,
                                   Some(ref trait_type),
                                   ref for_type) = item.node {
        } else {
//            item2 = *item; // AAA
            item2 = item.unwrap(); // BBB
        }
    }
}
```

Produce the compile-time error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `item` because it is borrowed
  --> /home/xxx/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-07-29-204629/snippet.rs:64:21
   |
61 |                                    ref for_type) = item.node {
   |                                                    ---- borrow of `item` occurs here
...
64 |             item2 = item.unwrap();
```

I do not understand two things:

1. Why does it complain about the borrow in the `if` branch while we in `else` branch? They are supposed to be mutually exclusive, and a borrow in one should not influence another.
2. If I replace `Vec` in `let mut items = Vec::<P<Item>>::new();` with `Vec<Box<Item>>` and uncomment line `AAA` and comment line `BBB`, then it compiles. Both `Box` and `P` implement `Deref`, so the `item.node` expression should be the same.

Comment: Your first question has already been answered - [If let borrow conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30243606/155423). Please remove it from your question. This is [why you should only ask one question per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a much clearer example:

```
struct Item;

struct P<T> {
    ptr: Box<T>,
}

impl<T> P<T> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Self {
        P { ptr: Box::new(v) }
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::Deref for P<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.ptr
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut item = P::new(Item);
    // let mut item = Box::new(Item);

    *item;
}
```

> Both `Box` and `P` implement `Deref`, so the `item.node` expression should be the same.

Hard truth time: moving out of `Box` is [special-cased in the compiler](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/10/rust-tidbits-box-is-special/). It does **not** use `Deref`. Moving out of a `Box` deallocates the memory and gives you ownership. It is not possible to implement this special ability ourselves.

*Maybe* at some point in the future a *hypothetical* trait like `DerefMove` will be added. This trait is hard to get right. There have been a [number of attempts for an RFC for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/search?q=DerefMove&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), but none are currently open.

See also:

- [Dereferencing Box<T> gives back value instead of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33653946/155423)
- [How can I reuse a box that I have moved the value out of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38397163/155423)