# Why can I mutably borrow separate fields from a Box, but not other ref types?

Tags: rust

With a simple object, I can get mutable references to individual fields:

```
struct MyObject {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
}

fn func_1(obj: &mut MyObject) {
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b;

    *a += 1;
    *b *= 2;
}
```

This doesn't work if `obj` is a `MutexGuard` or `RefMut`:

```
fn func_3(mtx: &Mutex<MyObject>) {
    let mut obj = mtx.lock().unwrap();
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b; // fails
    ...
}

fn func_4(rfc: &mut RefCell<MyObject>) {
    let mut obj = rfc.borrow_mut();
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b; // fails
    ...
}
```

Both fail with:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `obj` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:28:18
   |
27 |     let a = &mut obj.a;
   |                  --- first mutable borrow occurs here
28 |     let b = &mut obj.b; // fails
   |                  ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

However, this **does** work if `obj` is a `Box`:

```
fn func_2(obj: &mut Box<MyObject>) {
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b;

    *a += 1;
    *b *= 2;
}
```

See it on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8b53482e8f55fe4df77c8d3fa3d8c3e).

My main question is why. Why does the compiler know that this is okay for `Box`, but not for the others? Is `Box` special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the ways in which `Box` is still special, despite rather a lot of effort having been put into making it appear like any other type.

`RefMut` is implemented in plain Rust. The reason you can take references to a member like `&mut obj.a` is because `RefMut` implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`, and the compiler uses `DerefMut` to take an `&mut RefMut<'_, MyObject>` and turn it into a `&mut MyObject` to access the field. But the compiler doesn't know that the borrow of `obj.a` is disjoint from the borrow of `obj.b` because the implementation of `DerefMut` is opaque.

`Box` is different because dereferencing a `Box<T>` does *not* go through `Deref` or `DerefMut` (except in a generic context). Instead, the compiler has special code that knows what a `Box<T>` is and how to dereference it to get a `T`. This is how the compiler knows that `obj.a` and `obj.b` are disjoint for `Box<T>`, but not for `RefMut<'_, T>` or `MutexGuard<'_, T>`.

`Box` is the only type that is special in this particular way.

#### Other links about the specialness of `Box`

- [Rust Tidbits: Box Is Special](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/10/rust-tidbits-box-is-special/)
- [Why do I get "cannot move out of `item` because it is borrowed" for a custom type but not a Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45392688/3650362)
- [Why can I not borrow a variable as mutable more than once at a time with a &mut Box<T> while &mut T works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50237774/3650362)

Comment: So, for consistency's sake, should I avoid using this "feature" and just treat it like a normal `Deref`?

Comment: @kmdreko If you obtain a `&mut T` out of an `&mut impl Deref<T>` by using `&mut*myDerefValue`, then the regular rules will apply once more.